# Azure Data Factory connecting to Salesforce - error

Tags: salesforce, azure-data-factory

I got linked service in ADF and working fine. Here is my configuration.

[image]

But now is throwing error.  Updated Security Token ... still same issue

```
    Error details
    Error code
    9603
    Details
    ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][Salesforce] (22) Error parsing XML response from Salesforce: not
 well-formed (invalid token) at line 1 ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][Salesforce] (22) Error parsing 
XML response from Salesforce: not well-formed (invalid token) at line 1 Activity ID: b9d0f650-
d863-45ce-bf7a-cb668acc3ecf.
```

Comment: In SF find your user details in setup, scroll down to login history. Do you actually see an entry in there? With success or error? If there's nothing about that time (and I think app name will be something like "simba technologies") - it couldn't match you so likely you passed wrong url or username. Do you use normal SF username and password or SSO?

Comment: We did this and the login was successful on SF side but we still get the error in ADF. Any solution to this?